# Pandas df.to_excel for multiple dfs?

Tags: python, excel, pandas

So I want to save 2 dataframes into 2 different worksheets, but the same file.
My code for this part is:

```
df.to_excel(path, sheet name = 'sheet1')
df2.to_excel(path, sheet name = 'sheet2')
```

And for some reason the code ignores the first part, the excel file only has sheet2 with df2 on it, sheet1 is nowhere to be found. Before I added the df2 part the code saved the df perfectly fine.
Why is that, how could I fix this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use a writer for this:

```
with pd.ExcelWriter(output_file) as writer:
    for i,df in enumerate(list_of_dfs, start=1):
        df.to_excel(writer, sheet_name= 'sheet'+str(i))

    writer.save()
```

Comment: I am getting an xlrd.XLDError: Zip file contents now a known type of workbook for some reason, even tho it saved the files with pd.to_excel :/